# Get the line count from 2nd line of the file

Tags: linux, bash

How do I get the line count of a file from the 2nd line of the file, as the first line is header?

```
wc -l filename
```

Is there a way to set some condition into it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `tail` command:

```
tail -n +2 file | wc -l
```

`-n +2` would print the file starting from line 2

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk to count from 2nd line onwards:

```
awk 'NR>1{c++} END {print c}' file
```

Or simply use `NR` variable in the `END` block:

```
awk 'END {print NR-1}' file
```

Alternatively using BASH arithmetic subtract 1 from `wc` output:

```
echo $(( $(wc -l < file) -1 ))
```

Answer (score 2):

Delete first line with GNU sed:

```
sed '1d' file | wc -l
```

Comment: I guess that should work with any sed, not just GNU sed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tweak the `wc` command itself. You should whether process the result of the command, or use another tool.

As suggested in other answers, if you are running Bash, a good way is to put the result of the command into an arithmetic expression like `$(( $(command) - 1 ))`.

In case if you are searching for a portable solution, here is a Perl version:

```
perl -e '1 while <>; print $. - 1' < file
```

The variable `$.` holds the number of lines read since a file handle was last closed. The `while` loop reads all the lines from the `file`.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, you could just subtract 2.

```
echo $((`cat FILE | wc -l`-2))
```

Comment: Useless use of `cat`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one. It will be solved your problem

```
 $ tail -n +2 filename | wc -l
```